# Configuring multi-tenancy

Tags: python, django, mezzanine, multi-tenant

In a local dev env, I'm currently attempting to hack my way to multi-tenancy using Mezzanine:

*Mezzanine makes use of Django’s sites app to support multiple sites in a single project. This functionality is always “turned on” in Mezzanine:*

That's pretty much as far as an entry-level tut for multi-tenancy on mezzanine gets. Great, so I go to the admin site, and add a site:

---

Domain name-----|----Display name

127.0.0.1:8000----|----English Site

127.0.0.1:8000/es|----Spanish Site

---

Now, I am stuck. I have fiddled around with url.py, but figured that's not where to start, considering I need to know something to map the url to. Views? Lost.

Any ideas?

(Included translation is not an option given the web service will never translate as good as a human.)

Answer (score 2):

Multitenancy in mezzanine is done via domain names. You will need to run http://dev.site and http://esdev.site or similar in development (add the entries to your hosts file and make sure they match the listings in the sites part of admin).

In production you'll also want to use two different domains too.

For example, my personal site http://dpn.name/ and my business site http://behest.com.au/ are both running off the same mezzanine install.

Later on when you have the right setup, you'll be able to add new posts and pages to each specific site by either logging into the admin via each domain name, or changing the currently active site in the admin (the drop down is in the top right if you have multiple sites set up)

Hope that helps, please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dpn. I am resorting to Multi-tenancy in order to translate the site with admin-generated copy. For the sake of not buying another domain but also for SEO and many other design/architecture reasons, I want to use the same domain with different slug...

Comment: @shiva my understanding is that is not directly possible with mezzanine as it stands. Surely you could just run a subdomain?  http://es.example.com and http://example.com.

Comment: A though occured to me, I don't think this is ideal, but it may do what you need: run two instances internally on different internal domains and then use nginx to reverse proxy back to the right instance  depending on whether they arre at /en or /.  Not sure if you have the hosting flexibility to do this. 

I really would go for the subdomain option :)